# Algorithm to generate positive random integers smaller than given integer n

Tags: algorithm, random

There are algorithms to generate random numbers like:

```
number = (previous_number * constant + other_constant) mod third_constant
```

for carefully selected constants.
But I need algorithm to generate random integers that are in range of 0 to n-1. (Obviously not running loop and getting the counter, I need randomness). How is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Uhh, is there a particular reason you don't want to use some form of `rand()`?

Comment: Yup, I want algorithm :)

Comment: You could always use [the XKCD method](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Answer (score 2):

Use third_constant = n

The multiply and add operations give you some number, then when you do the mod you get an integer from 0 to third_constant -1, so just use n for the third_constant and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by generating a pseudo-random number in range `[0,1)` (which exists in most languages), and then :

```
r = rand()
res = floor(rand*m)
```

One way to generate a random in `[0,1)` is to generate random integer in `[0,MAX_RAND)`, and divide by `MAX_RAND`.

---

You can also use a random int generation from [0,MAX_RAND) (let it be `r`, and return `r % m` - but beware of bias if `MAX_RAND` is not significantly larger than `m` (by 2-3 scales)

Comment: I don't think OP will accept this. Said that `rand()` can't be used for some unspecified reason...

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist He has a working random int generation according to question, I showed how to create this `rand()` from it.

Comment: Are you sure? "I need algorithm to generate random integers that are in range of 0 to n-1... How is this possible?" doesn't sound like it to me.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes, his algorithm is exactly the suggested on in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods). The point is he has a random number in an arbitrary range (he cannot decide), and want a random in shorter range, as far as I can understand.